# How to display MapBox data using ARCGIS JS API?

Tags: mapbox, esri, arcgis-js-api, vector-tiles

Suppose, I've a MapBox Dataset in the form of an URL/Link. How to display that data in a Web Application that uses ArcGIS-js-API.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sample app, to use Mapbox Style as a Web Tile Layer in Arcgis-JS-API 4.4. Uses Mapbox DatasetID to visualise Popup content of that Mapbox style/Data.

Helps to Visualise & Interact with Mapbox data using an ARCGIS JS API 4.4 application

https://github.com/hostasite/MapboxDataUsingArcGis4.4

Answer (score 1):

If your Mapbox Dataset is GeoJSON, you could use [geojson-layer-js](https://github.com/Esri/geojson-layer-js) to add the layer to the map.

Comment: Thats great. Thank you for your time & help. I will try that. Also, I want to check whether geojson-layer-js support MapBox Vector Tiles? Thank you in advance.